# tomcat has been stopped

Tags: java, xml, tomcat

Hi my tomcat is not working , It says an error saying

**SEVERE: Parse Fatal Error at line 122 column 9: The element type "Engine" must be 
   terminated
   by the matching end-tag "".**

**org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/D:/tomcat/conf/server.xml; lineNumber: 122; 
    columnNumber: 9; The element type "Engine" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "

   ".**

here is my **server.xml**

```
      <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
      <!--
      Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
       contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
      this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
      The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
      (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
         the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

        Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
       distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
         WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
       See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
      limitations under the License.
        -->
      <!-- Note:  A "Server" is not itself a "Container", so you may not
       define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
            Documentation at /docs/config/server.html
       -->
        <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
       <!-- Security listener. Documentation at /docs/config/listeners.html
        <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener" />
       -->
        <!--APR library loader. Documentation at /docs/apr.html -->
       <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener"      
       SSLEngine="on" />
      <!--Initialize Jasper prior to webapps are loaded. Documentation at /docs/jasper-
      howto.html -->
        <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
        <!-- Prevent memory leaks due to use of particular java/javax APIs-->
       <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" 
        />
       <Listener
       className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
       <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"
         />

          <!-- Global JNDI resources
         Documentation at /docs/jndi-resources-howto.html
          -->
         <GlobalNamingResources>
         <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
            UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
             -->
          <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
          type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
          description="User database that can be updated and saved"
          factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
          pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
          </GlobalNamingResources>

           <!-- A "Service" is a collection of one or more "Connectors" that share
            a single "Container" Note:  A "Service" is not itself a "Container",
            so you may not define subcomponents such as "Valves" at this level.
                 Documentation at /docs/config/service.html
             -->
           <Service name="Catalina">

            <!--The connectors can use a shared executor, you can define one or more  
            named thread pools-->
            <!--
             <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-"
              maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="4"/>
             -->


             <!-- A "Connector" represents an endpoint by which requests are received
          and responses are returned. Documentation at :
           Java HTTP Connector: /docs/config/http.html (blocking & non-blocking)
           Java AJP  Connector: /docs/config/ajp.html
             APR (HTTP/AJP) Connector: /docs/apr.html
            Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080
            -->
          <Connector port="9999" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
           <!-- A "Connector" using the shared thread pool-->
           <!--
           <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool"
           port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
           -->
          <!-- Define a SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8443
          This connector uses the JSSE configuration, when using APR, the
            connector should be using the OpenSSL style configuration
            described in the APR documentation -->
           <!--
           <Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
           maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
            -->

           <!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
           <Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />


            <!-- An Engine represents the entry point (within Catalina) that processes
             every request.  The Engine implementation for Tomcat stand alone
            analyzes the HTTP headers included with the request, and passes them
            on to the appropriate Host (virtual host).
            Documentation at /docs/config/engine.html -->

            <!-- You should set jvmRoute to support load-balancing via AJP ie :
            <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">
             -->
         <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">

               <!--For clustering, please take a look at documentation at:
             /docs/cluster-howto.html  (simple how to)
               /docs/config/cluster.html (reference documentation) -->
                  <!--
            <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
               -->

               <!-- Use the LockOutRealm to prevent attempts to guess user passwords
              via a brute-force attack -->
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
             driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
             connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/AndroidIM"
             connectionName="gokul"
             connectionPassword="abcd"
              userTable="TABLE_NAME_MESSAGES" userNameCol="username" 
             userCredCol="password"
              userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role" />

            </Realm>

            <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
            unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

             <!-- SingleSignOn valve, share authentication between web applications
               Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html -->
                <!--
             <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn" />
              -->

              <!-- Access log processes all example.
            Documentation at: /docs/config/valve.html
             Note: The pattern used is equivalent to using pattern="common" -->
              <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
            directory="logs"
           prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
           pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />

              </Host>
            </Engine>
            </Service>
            </Server>
```

can anybody help me to clear the error,...the tag they have specified is there at the end..but it is not working !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `<Realm>` end tags to many.

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JDBCRealm"
driverName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
connectionURL="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8888/AndroidIM"
connectionName="gokul"
connectionPassword="abcd"
userTable="TABLE_NAME_MESSAGES" userNameCol="username" 
userCredCol="password"
userRoleTable="user_roles" roleNameCol="role" />

</Realm> <!-- Remove this -->
```